# observing property changes to an ObjectProxy in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Following this tutorial on how to use checkboxes with ember: http://www.poeticsystems.com/blog/ember-checkboxes-and-you.

Everything works great. Except now I'd like to listen for when the property 'checked' changes in the object. Here is my code:

```
someArray: Ember.computed 'proxiedCheckedItems.[]', ->
    // should fire whenever an item is checked. But it does not.
    console.debug("CD: detected change here")
    // return some array

proxiedModel: Ember.computed.map 'someArray', (model) ->
    Ember.ObjectProxy.create({
        content: model,
        checked: false
    })

proxiedCheckedItems: Ember.computed.filterBy('proxiedModel', 'checked', true)
```

so, observing `proxiedCheckedItems.[]` is wrong. I've tried `proxiedCheckedItems.@each` and `proxiedCheckedItems.checked`. Nothing works. So how do you observe an array of ObjectProxy in Ember?

Comment: What's your template look like in this? The `.[]` will observe the length so that seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have circular computed properties. `someArray` depends on `proxiedCheckedItems`, which depends on `proxiedModel`, which depends on `someArray`! I honestly can't say what is happening in your situation, but I can tell you that Ember isn't set up to handle circularly dependent properties. Chances are you're invoking some sort of undefined behavior.

Comment: #1 is wrong. `proxiedCheckedItems` is an array who's length changes when any of it's property's `.checked` value changes. The `proxiedCheckedItems.[]` is correct in this case.